# Magento 2 Product Short Description Truncate?

Tags: magento2.2, product-attribute, magento2-migration-tool

I've migrated Magento 1 to Magento 2, In the Magento 1 site on product listing page I've truncated the length of the short description.

**e.g- echo Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($short_description, '120');**

I require the same thing in Magento 2 way, how can I achieve it?

Note:- I don't want to use simple core PHP to restrict length.

Comment: Check my below solution and let me know if working or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can truncate string in Magento-2 by below code

Inject below parameters to your class __construct

```
protected $filter;

public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filter
    ) {
        $this->filter = $filter;
   }
```

You can truncate string by below code

```
$this->filter->truncate($short_description, ['length' => 120]));
```

Comment: Sorry! I was engaged on some other urgent works so looked on this late.thanks for the reply.i tried but it didn't work in  the class "Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct".

Comment: any error or not working?

Comment: Getting errors, so i tried helper way & it works.

Comment: I've used cache:clean. when we need to delete generated? i used the same using helper but it works without deleting generated why?

Comment: keep in mind if you add any constructor argument, It required delete generated folder. if you clean just cache it will be not working and throw error.

Comment: Thanks for the information.Have you checked same code via block,is this work for you? by using helper i also used constructor but didn't need to delete generated folder?

Answer (score 0):

After spending two hours approx I've done this by using a helper.

**Helper Path:-**

Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList.php(I'll be overriding later so you can also).

**Added Following code:-**

```
    // Extends class \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper

class ProductList extends \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper
     public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Filter\FilterManager $filter
          ) {
              $this->filter = $filter;
            }
                // My custom method
         public function truncateString($value, $length = 80)
            {
                return $this->filter->truncate($value, ['length' => $length]) ;
            }
```

**// In the template file, just called custom method:-**

```
 $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product\ProductList')->truncateString($short_description,120);
```

**Note:-** I tried to do it using block but due to the time restriction i'm not able will try later. if anyone do the same via block then please share here.